# Large venue augmented reality

Tags: android-camera, augmented-reality, vuforia

What are all the hardware (camera) and software requirements for big screen augmented reality? Is there any workaround to use Vuforia and smartphone to display on a large LED screen?

Comment: It's hard to answer with so few details - how large? what distance? And most important - did you try it and found a problem?

Comment: The LED display would be 13 ft x 7 ft kept at a distance of 6 ft from viewers. I have created mobile based AR using vuforia. The target image can be recognised at 6ft distance using mobile. This distance can be increased by increasing the target image size. So, does the large venue need a bigger target image? what if people hide the target? Or a SLAM based approach is needed? Also to use a LED display will mobile output be enough? (based on mobile camera capabilities like MP, focal length, clarity, recognition etc.,)

Comment: Regarding "Also to use a LED display will mobile output be enough" - it is not clear what you're asking, please elaborate on that

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it will work if the target is big enough and the mobile device camera is good enough. But it will be very difficult for you to get exact answers I think - you need to test it or simulate it.

Regarding if people hide the target - again, you need to figure out yourself what the scenario is and how bad can it be. If it's very crowded and people are hiding the target constantly, using only target-based solution is not enough. If you're only talking about hiding here and there, you can use Vuforia's Extended Tracking for that.